# Use a formula stored in an object for the raster function overlay

Tags: r, r-raster

I have been struggling with an issue for several hours and I am currently having a very hard trying to find a workaround.

I want to use the `overlay` function of the `raster` package. This function combines multiple rasters (or raster layers of a stack) into a new raster according to a specific function, such as a mathematical function.

Here is a practical example:

```
library(raster)
# First we create an example raster stack with two layers
a <- matrix(rep(dnorm(1:100, 50, sd = 25)),
            nrow = 100, ncol = 100, byrow = TRUE)
env <- stack(raster(a * dnorm(1:100, 50, sd = 25) * 10000),
             raster(a * 1:100))
names(env) <- c("variable1", "variable2")
plot(env)
```

[image]

```
# Second, we combine them with a simple addition
raster3 <- overlay(env, fun = function(variable1, variable2) variable1 + variable2)
plot(raster3)
```

[image: The resulting raster after combination with overlay]

So, in the example above, our raster has two variables called `variable1` and `variable2`, and we apply the formula `variable1 + variable2` on them.

## The problem

I am trying to use overlay within a function, in which I have:

- the input raster stack (the number of layers is variable, as well as the names of layers). A typical example is the stack `env` above.
- the formula (the formula is always written based on layer names of the input raster stack). Typical examples are `variable1 + variable2` or `variable1 * variable2 + 3 * variable1`.

## My (unsuccessful) attempts

I was able to use a formula previously stored as a string in an object:

```
form <- "variable1 + 3 * variable2"
raster4 <- overlay(env, fun = function(variable1, variable2) eval(parse(text = form)))
```

This works; however, you can notice that I still had to specify `variable1` and `variable2` as arguments. I am not able to figure out how to automatically provide layer names as arguments in fun.

I tried:

```
overlay(env, fun = function(...) eval(parse(text = form)))
overlay(env, fun = function(names(env)) eval(parse(text = form)))
```

but these obviously did not work. I am already using the terrible `eval(parse())` procedure within the function, I would like to find a solution which will not require me to write a general `eval(parse())` script encompassing the whole `overlay`.

Any insights will be greatly appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Here is an ugly workaround using `eval(parse())`

The aim is to create a function which adapts to the input `raster` and `formula`.

- Example with the formula `variable1 + variable2`

.

```
form <- "variable1 + variable2"
input.raster <- env
eval(parse(text = paste("custom.overlay <- function(",
                        paste(names(input.raster), collapse = ", "),
                        ") {",
                        form,
                        "}"
)))
raster4 <- overlay(env, fun = custom.overlay)
plot(raster4)
```

[image]

- Another example with the formula `variable1^2 + 3 * variable2`

.

```
form <- "variable1^2 + 3 * variable2"
input.raster <- env
eval(parse(text = paste("custom.overlay <- function(",
                        paste(names(input.raster), collapse = ", "),
                        ") {",
                        form,
                        "}"
)))
raster5 <- overlay(env, fun = custom.overlay)
plot(raster5)
```

[image]

It works in both cases. But it's not a very elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

You should not refer to the variable names, but to their position. Then you can do, for example:

```
library(raster)
a <- matrix(rep(dnorm(1:100, 50, sd = 25)), nrow = 100, ncol = 100, byrow = TRUE)
env <- stack(raster(a * dnorm(1:100, 50, sd = 25) * 10000), raster(a * 1:100))

v <- overlay(env, fun=function(x,y) x * y + 3 - sqrt(y / x))
```

And without the "eval(parse(text = form)" business, your example works fine for me:

```
raster4 <- overlay(env, fun = function(variable1, variable2) variable1 + 3 * variable2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @RobertH . 
Unfortunately this is used inside [a package](https://github.com/Farewe/virtualspecies/blob/master/R/generateSpFromFun.R) where users can provide a formula as a string. I can never be sure about the position of variables in both the formula and the raster stack, which is why I wanted to work with names. 
I really do not know how to set up a function for the argument `fun` of `overlay` without using `eval(parse())`.